# Two-sided moving average in python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, moving-average

Hi I have some data and I want to compute the centered moving average or two-sided moving average.

I've understood how easy this can be done with the numpy.convolve function and I wonder if there is an easy or similar way in which this can be done, but when the average needs to be two-sided.

The one sided moving average usually works in the following way if the interval contains three entries, N = 3:

```
import numpy
list = [3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10]
N = 3
window = numpy.repeat(1., N)/N
moving_avg = numpy.convolve(list, window, 'valid')
moving_avg = array([ 4.66666667,  6.33333333,  8.        ,  9.        ])
```

Now what I am aiming to get is the average that is centered, so that if N = 3, the intervals over which the mean is taken are: [[3, 4, 7], [4, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10]]. This is also tricky if N is an even number. Is there a tool to compute this? I'd prefer to do it either by writing a function or using numpy.

Comment: How do these differ?

Comment: In the "easy case" the average is taken over the interval with boundaries on the left, e,g, you can't take the average over an interval of 3 for the first two entries, then the first average will be take for [3+4+4], the second one will be [4+7+8], then [7+8+9] and so on. However, I am more interested in what happens when I take the average where my value is centered (i.e. the intervals I wrote). With the example I gave there may not be much difference. However my real arrays are much more larger and time-dependent, what the centered average may tell me is if there's a physical effect.

Comment: But, it is the SAME average.  The only difference is which index you attribute it to.

Comment: Yes, except that for the first entry, there the average in one case is 3.6 and in the other case is 4.6. I guess that for my much larger arrays as they are time-variant the same won't happen, i.e. that I will get the same average. For one of those N>500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the commenters, I'm also confused what you're trying to accomplish that's different than the way you demonstrated.

In any case, I did want to offer a solution that lets you write your own convolution operations using [Numba's `@stencil` decorator](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/stencil.html):

```
from numba import stencil

@stencil
def ma(a):
    return (a[-1] + a[0] + a[1]) / 3

data = np.array([3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10])
print(ma(data))
[0.         4.66666667 6.33333333 8.         9.         0.        ]
```

Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for, but the stencil operator is great. The variable you pass it represents a given element, and any indexing you use is relative to that element. As you can see, it was pretty easy to make a 3-element window to calculate a moving average.

Hopefully this gives you what you need.

### Using a Large Neighborhood

You can add a parameter to the stencil, which is inclusive. Let's make a neighborhood of 9:

```
@stencil(neighborhood = ((-4, 4),))
def ma(a):
    cumul = 0
    for i in range(-4, 5):
        cumul += a[i]
    return cumul / 9
```

You can shift the range forward or back with (-8, 0) or (0, 8) and changing the range.

### Setting N Neighborhood

Not sure if this is the best way, but I accomplished it with a wrapper:

```
def wrapper(data, N):
    @nb.stencil(neighborhood = ((int(-(N-1)/2), int((N-1)/2)),))
    def ma(a):
        cumul = 0
        for i in np.arange(int(-(N-1)/2), int((N-1)/2)+1):
            cumul += a[i]
        return cumul / N
    return ma(data)
```

Again, indexing is weird, so you'll have to play with it to get the desired effect.

Comment: Hi, many thanks! That actually works! I'm sorry I didn't explain myself properly, but I guess you understood my aim!

Comment: Just one question, this works only if N = 3, but what if the value is much more larger?

Comment: Yeah, the documentation actually demonstrates using a much larger neighborhood. I added an example to the answer.

Comment: I'm confused, although the neighbourhood is 9, you define it from (-4, 4)?

Comment: Yeah the range is inclusive for some reason ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. From what I can tell, playing with the neighborhood parameter impacts how it deals with borders.

Comment: I guess that only happens for odd numbers?

Comment: Can I ask you another silly question. I'm trying to generalise the function so that I can use it easily for many arrays. However, I'm not sure of how to pass a variable to the argument of the decorator. I was typing something like @stencil(neighborhood = ((-(N-1)/2, (N-1)/2),). For one set I want N = 431, for another one 589, etc. but my code says I haven't defined N. Clearly I'm not passing N correctly. Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I added my stab at it to the answer. Just used a wrapper function, but I had to define the moving average as a sub function (couldn't figure out a handy lambda way to do it). I'm willing to bet there's a clever way to do it more directly, but I'm spent.

Comment: Thanks, while you answered that's exactly what I had done!